# PHP cURL gives error at crontab, but through ssh it works perfect

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, php-curl

I've made a php script, that i want to excecute on my ubuntu 16.04 machine. I am working with php 7 and i use crontab.

When i run the command `which php` this is the output:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Now my script is uploading a picture on a website. I use PHP curl for that. This is my cURL setup

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->mUrl . $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

This is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash  -x
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/www/{PROGRAM}
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/{NAME1}/{PROGRAM}_autopost.php
```

This is my cron file

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/{program}/cronjob.sh > /tmp/outputvancron
```

And this is the part where the script gives an error

```
public function Post($photo, $caption){
    $response = $this->PostImage($photo);
    if(empty($response[1])) {
        echo "Empty response received from the server while trying to post the image";
        exit();
    }

    $obj = @json_decode($response[1], true);
    $status = $obj['status'];
    if($status == 'ok') {
        $media_id = $obj['media_id'];
        $response = $this->PostCaption($caption, $media_id);
    }
}
```

There is no response from the server. But when i start the bash manually with the command

```
bash cronjob.sh
```

It works perfect.

How can it be that crontab can't finish my script, but through shell i can?

Please help me out.

**EDIT**

I am using curl_exec($ch);

```
private function Request($url, $post, $post_data, $cookies) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->mUrl . $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);

    if($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if ((version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5') >= 0)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 1);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    }

    if($cookies) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,   dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt');
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt');
    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array($http, $response);
}
```

Comment: This is (at least) the 3rd time you are posting the same question, and you are still missing the `curl_exec()`  in your PHP script, which was the problem pointed out to your several times, but which you continue to ignore. Would appreciate if you would stop re-posting your question and start working with the feedback you get from the community.

Comment: Can you at least help me how i should do this? I really don't understand what to do.

Comment: I did an edit. Look, i listened. It is just still not working. I am just trying to get some help, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you for adding the rest of the code. Apparently there was a lot missing including the curl_exec(). Now there is a much better chance to actually helping you with your question.

Comment: now, do you have any idea how i could fix the problem? And if no one replies because of the 2 downvotes, is it okay to repost? @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Have you tried to reduce all your code down to just a test curl action within a php you run from cron and commandline, that purely pours out its responses and any error codes and php errors? Or does that all work, and its just your class and methods that are losing the response in the arrays passed around? Because I do not see how `$response` gets from method `Request` through `$response = $this->PostImage($photo);` ... missing code, and it would just be too much code for you to post the whole class.

Comment: Please do not repost. I removed my down-vote, see.. you are back to 0

Comment: @IncredibleHat i did a test curl action through cron, it gave no errors. So it seems to be something in my script. It would be too much code to post the whole class.  I think my class is losing the response, but i think it is very strange, because it only happens with cron.

Comment: Yeah, it does sound odd that it would get lost in the chain only during cron, and not cmdline. You may have to start reducing/testing/debugging your class a bit and see whats going on. Time to pepper it with echo's and breaks and debug debug debug :(